# Why is the Army Camp showing more troops then I have?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I am new to Clash of Clans.  My problem is when I try to create new troops it stops producing because my camp is full.   But my camp capacity is 65, and I have created only 33 troops.  One thing to mention:  this amount is decreasing when I come back from an attack.  Can anyone tell me where the problem is?
[image: Cropped screenshot showing 65 of 65 troops]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [wiki](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Giant), Giants use 5 housing space each.  You have 8 Giants which use 40 housing space plus 25 troops that use 1 housing space each.

8*5 + (5 + 11 + 9) * 1 = 40 + 25 = 65

Comment: Yeah, each troop has a set Housing Space they occupy, which can be checked by going under you're barracks and tapping/clicking the blue "i" by the troop icon.